# Displaying a TextView depending on whether Android permission is disabled?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-support-library, android-permissions

I'm trying to display a `TextView` which appears visible only when a particular Android `permission`, i.e. `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, is not enabled. The idea is to explain to the user why they need to enable it in case they've disabled it the first time, and then have them click the `TextView` to launch the permission request again. The following is not working for me. How can I accomplish this? I have this in my `onCreate()` method:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
} else {
    if (NetworkHelper.isOnline(this)) {
        new AppendParseData().execute();
    }
}

TextView checkFilePermission = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkFilePermission);

if (!checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
    checkFilePermission.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: What problem getting using current code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to display a TextView when the user denies a permission. The idea is to check if they accepted it or not in onCreate then display it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming *questions*. This is not a question.

Comment: I added a question mark. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way when you request for permission(I have used `READ_CONTACTS` permission you can use `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` instead)

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestContactsPermissions1();
            } else {
                setTextVisablity(false);
                checkSimCard();
            }
```

in `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission Granted
                    readContacts();
                    setTextVisablity(false);
                } else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    setTextVisablity(true);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "READ_CONTACTS Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

in the end `setTextVisablity` method

```
public void setTextVisablity(boolean isShow) {
        if (isShow) {
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code:-


int hasWriteContactsPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
            return;
    }
    else{
        //Permission already granted show textview here
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission Granted                   
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " PERMISSION_GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                     .show();
                } else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```